# Is $f(x + iy) = x + 2i (x+y)$ holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

So $u(x, y) = x$ and $v(x, y) = 2(x+y)$

So the Riemann-Cauchy equations do not hold, since

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 1 \neq 2 = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

I am specifically asking because I am unsure whether the $2$ is part of the function $v$ or not.

Comment: yes,the imaginary part of $f$ is $v(x,y)=2(x+y)$. We are assuming here that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if youre unsure about the 2, you can see that the second of the  Cauchy -Riemann differential equations is also not satisfied, no matter if there is the factor 2 or not:
$$
 \frac{du}{dy} = 0 \neq -a = -\frac{d v}{dx}
$$
with $a = 1$ or $a = 2$ or any other $a \neq 0$. Since for holomorphic functions the C-R Equations hold, you know that your given function cannot be holomorphic.